# Как из PHP запросить BOOLEAN поле из Firebird?

Tags: php, firebird

Пример кода:

```
  $db = 'localhost:C:\...path...\dbname.fdb';
  $username = 'SYSDBA';
  $password = 'masterkey';

  // Подключение к БД
  $dbhandle = ibase_connect($db, $username, $password) or die ("error in db connect");
  $status = ($dbhandle != '');
  if ($status) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';

    // Выполняем запрос
    $rc = ibase_query($dbhandle, $sql);
    echo "rc: ".$rc."]<br><br>";
    // Получаем результат построчно в виде объекта
    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) {
      echo $row->FIELD_NAME."<br>";
    }
    // Освобождаем хэндл связанный с результатом запроса
    ibase_free_result($rc);
    // Освобождаем хэндл связанный с подключением
    ibase_close($dbhandle);
  }
```

Если в списке полей выборки присутствует поле типа `BOOLEAN`, то получаю предупреждение

> Warning: ibase_fetch_object(): Incorrect values within SQLDA structure empty pointer to data at SQLVAR index 5 in D:...\test.php on line 33

и никаких данных... Собственно вопрос, как обратиться к `BOOLEAN` полю? В Менеджере DB запрос отрабатывается корректно.

Comment: Какая версия FB? Какая версия PHP коннектора? Поддерживает ли Ваш PHP коннектор Вашу версию FB?

Comment: Если бы не поддерживала, работали бы запросы к простым таблицам, а к вьюшкам нет? серьёзно?

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда ищите проблему самостоятельно

Comment: Это был простой вопрос... Зачем такая реакция? PHP Version 5.6.30 FB: v3.0, коннектор fbclient.dll v3.0(из того же пакета FB)

Comment: Это Вы указали версию клиента (кстати, Вы уверены, что именно эта dll загружается)? А я Вас спрашиваю о версии расширения PHP php_interbase.dll или чем Вы пользуетесь?

Comment: А есть еще такое расширения php_pdo_firebird.dll

Comment: pdo не ставил, но я и не через него работаю
interbase
Firebird/InterBase Support  dynamic
Compile-time Client Library Version  Firebird API version 25
Run-time Client Library Version  WI-V6.3.2.32703 Firebird 3.0

Comment: А покажите типы полей у вьюхи? BOOLEAN там нет?

Comment: А ведь точно! Если с нуля считать, как раз с 5 поля начинаются BOOL. На них какие-то ограничения чтоли есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь выбрать поле с типом `BOOLEAN`. Суть в том, что этот тип появился гораздо позднее, чем произошло отделение FireBird от Interbase. Как следствие этот тип имеет разные идентификаторы и разную структуру в IB и FB.

- Для Interbase этот тип имеет код 590, занимает два байта и может принимать значения `FALSE`, `TRUE`
- В Firebird тип имеет код 32764, занимает один байт и принимает значения `FALSE`, `TRUE`, `UNKNOWN`.

Расширение `php_interbase.dll` предназначено для работы с Interbase и, соответственно, ничего о типе 32764 не знает.

Варианты решения проблемы

- Использовать расширения `php_pdo_firebird.dll`
- поискать в сети `php_firebird.dll`. Может кто-то занимался портированием `php_interbase.dll` под новые версии Firebird
- продолжать использовать `php_interbase.dll`, но тогда отказаться от всего специфического для Firebird функционала

Comment: Познавательно, благодарю! Попробую через pdo

Comment: Хотя, с другой стороны, это же view, можно просто к другому типу привести

Comment: @Isaev Лучше сразу переходите на PDO. Нюансов будет еще много. FB и IB это **разные** СУБД и не нужно инструментами от одной пытаться работать с другой

Comment: Да, через PDO всё отлично работает, даже удобнее... И ошибки отлавливать удобнее

Comment: только вот BOOL-поля возвращают всегда NULL. Это как-то решается?

Comment: @Isaev Попробуйте поставить версию PHP поновее. Все таки, 5.6 вышла довольно давно и о FB3 тогда мало, что знали

Comment: Поставил 7.2.2, не помогло

Comment: При чём при работе не с VIEW, а с обычной таблицей ведёт себя так же... независимо TRUE или FALSE, получаем NULL в ответе

Comment: @Isaev Таблица или вьюха - нет никакого значения. Попробуйте спросить здесь http://www.sql.ru/forum/interbase Там и разработчики FB сидят